# timespec.tv_sec always returns 0

Tags: c++, time, clock

I am just learning how to use clock_getres (there is almost no good documentation for this anywhere on the web).  My code looks like this:

```
timespec now;
clock_getres(CLOCK_REALTIME,&now);
std::cout<<statut_cast<int>(now.tv_sec)<<","<<static_cast<int>(now.tv_nsec)<<std::endl;
```

No matter when I run this code, the output is always 0,1
Can anybody explain why this doesn't work?

Comment: this is correct behaviour. what are you trying to do?

Comment: statut_cast<int> - never seen that before are you sure this is real code.

Comment: Perhaps on your system the OS decides to tell you the clock resolution is 1ns?

Comment: I am trying to get the current time in sec and nsec. Shouldn't the current time constantly be changing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `clock_gettime` to return the current time, not `clock_getres`, which returns the resolution of the clock.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/clock_getres.html:

> The `clock_getres()` function shall return the **resolution** of any clock.
>
> The `clock_gettime()` function shall return the current value `tp` for the specified clock, `clock_id`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the right behaviour - the output is `0,1` because the clock you are trying to get the resolution of has a nano-second resolution. Hence `now.tv_nsec=1` and `now.tv_sec=0`. If it did not have nanosecond resolution the output would be `0,0`.